# Java webservice client handling failover/cluster of webservice server

Tags: java, web-services, clustering

I am looking for a Java library that could help me invoke a webservice method and that can handle multiple webservers in case some of them are not responding. The idea is to enable failover when a cluster of servers provide the same webservice.

Some kind of scenario:

- client invokes method A on server 1
- server 1 is down
- automatically try server 2
- ...

Is there any such library available?

Comment: Are you asking about the client-side only, an app developer trying to access various web service servers? Or do you mean server-side failover handling to be employed by a sysadmin? Your Question seems to mention both.

Comment: My question is regarding the client  side only. Forgot to mention that it's using a jax-ws client.

Comment: You should edit your Question with additional info rather than post as comments. Use that "edit" link below your question (if using a web browser rather than app).

Answer (score 1):

## HTTP Client Libraries

Usually we do that kind of successive-URL-call work directly in our own code, using HTTP client libraries to assist.

HTTP client libraries such as [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org) [Google HTTP Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/), and [jsoup](http://jsoup.org) allow you to set a timeout, and they throw exceptions when various problems arise such as a [404](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/404_error).

So you write a series of cascading `if` statements trying each target URL in series until one succeeds. Setting those URLs, timeouts, and exception handling takes about the same code as would configuring some kind of library.

Comment: I forgot to mention that myclient is a jax-ws client and hence would prefr not tohave to reimplement this logic indiffrent places